# Sprockets Exclude Files From Compression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

Is it possible to exclude select files from being compressed when sprockets executes as part of the asset pipeline?

```
// application.css file
//
//= stub admin/vendor/jquery191
//= stub admin/vendor/jqueryui1102
//= stub admin/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap
```

For example, if I didn't want to slow down my deployment process by compressing bootstrap. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I dont think you should be doing that. First, assets compilation is not that long, second you can precompile before deploy so your deploy can be fast and third you can always fallback to not compiled version (until you actually compile it)

Comment: The gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3' recompile only the modified assets. It divided my deployment time by 3